# htaccess / rewrite rule problems... any ideas?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post

I've spent the last 24 hours looking for solutions to my problem both here and by searching google but I've been unable to find anything. Sorry if this is duplicated anywhere however.

For the last version of my site, written in php, I just had one index page which I used requests like this to grab the correct page:

```
?public=view/thispage
?page=account/loggedin
```

I'm now writing the new version of the site, also in php, and I'm trying to make it have search engine friendly urls / slugs for example

```
/page/view/thispage
/account/login
```

I've managed to get it so that virtual subdomains work for each client, using the top portion of the code below, and I've managed to get the slug pages to work using the bottom portion.

The problem I'm having is with forms, such as the form to sign up for the site, edit a user profile etc. I've read on this site that with apache rewrites $_POST variables should be passed to the script, unlike with redirects, but I'm using rewrite and when any form data is passed to a slug (for example /profile/edit) it doesn't work, although if it's passed to virtualsubdomain.mydomain.com/test.php for example it does.

Can anybody help me out and find a way to fix the htaccess file below and allow $_POST vars to be passed to my slug script (index.php in the code below)? There's probably just a small thing I'm missing.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomainhere.org
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).mydomainhere.org/^(.+)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://mydomainhere.org [P,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I can't work out why post vars can be read by php files that exist in the subdomains that are only virtual, but they can't be read when post them to a slug (such as /profile/editprofile). Global variables are off on my server but The following just brings up the default blanked variable so they obviously havent been passed.

```
$test = ''; //define the variable to please global vars off
$test = $_POST["namehere"];
echo $test;
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm fairly new to using htaccess files for anything other than just including a custom error file as you can probably tell.

Comment: Congratulations on your wall of text, but please reduce it to _"my URL's look like this and I want to rewrite then to that"_, because literally none of the non-code text in your question adds anything to the question itself. Besides - don't say your question is urgent. Everyone thinks their question is urgent. Furthermore I don't understand why you think `mod_rewrite` bugs with PHP's `$_POST` array; it doesn't. Your problem probably lies elsewhere.

Comment: I've already got the urls working... its post variables that aren't. I added detail as in every single example on here I've found with somebody trying to do the same thing somebody has replied with "please provide more detail about what you're trying to do"... to which the poster replied with what isn't working and then somebody posted "if you're using rewrite it should"... but for me it isnt. I didn't actually say I think theres a bug there tho... I said what I'm doing isn't working and I don't know why so simply asked for help :(

Comment: Do not know the reason why, but our client running Solaris had the very same problem - using .htaccess rewrites they were unable to pass POST to rewritten/redirected URL though apache should pass POST forward... BTW - put the line `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` before first `RewriteEngine on` and delete the second `RewriteEngine on` line...

Comment: Thanks for that... Those are two different blocks of code that I got from two different sources and just modified for my own use so I've tidied it up a bit... still no success on the post vars though :(

Comment: I've put up a test on my server, with the exact `.htaccess` contents you're providing, and my `index.php` dumps out the `$_POST` successfully. My guess is your problem has nothing to do with your rewrite rules. Can you try to remove the rewriting and submit directly to your `index.php` file, to rule out that something is wrong with it or with your form?

Comment: Your first `RewriteRule` will never match, by the way, since you require that `%{HTTP_HOST}` contains a string with slash and with a _second_ start-of-line anchor in it. The `HTTP_HOST` var contains only hostname, no path (thus no slashes).

Comment: When I submit directly to a php file that exists on the server my post variables are displayed, even though I'm using virtual subdomains.

The problem is when I submit to slug, for example /account/editprofile my script can't detect the post vars. The slug is required as it tells my index.php script which php script to include outside of the public_html folder and so sending it directly to index.php will detect the vars but my site won't know which script needs the vars.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only guessing because of Your .htaccess `RewriteCond` and other people having the same problem - You redirect any subdomain (except `www` or URL not containing `www.`) to your domain URL without `www.` - if I get it right:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomainhere.org
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).mydomainhere.org/^(.+)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://mydomainhere.org [P,L]
```

Then in Your forms You probably have URLs in `action` attribute tha do not contain `www.` therefore this action URLs gets redirected and the POST is probably lost...

Try to fill Your form `action` attribute with URLs containing `www.`:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.mydomainhere.org/my_page_to_post_to.php">
```

Maybe this will help...

Comment: I tried your idea but no luck :(. My form action is: <form method="post" action=/profile/editprofile"> as this loads up the errorpage which takes "/profile/editprofile" and runs it through the script to determine what php script to include in the template so sending it directly to a php file that exists works as far as reading the post variables, but that's as far as it will go as it won't load the scipt which determines where to send these variables.

Comment: Oh and I just thought of another thing... if I did that then it would completely remove the subdomain from the listing. This subdomain is used by my script to determine which client site to load and which client data to use from the database. client1.domain/view/news and client2.domain/view/news both include the same file, but fetch different data depending on what the subdomain is. Thanks anyway though :)

Comment: @ScottD Yes, but You could however fill the action with `http://client1.domain.com/view/news` or `http://client2.domain.com/view/news` or when no client then `http://www.domain.com/do/something`. Hmmm?

Comment: That's what I tried when you suggested it though... still no luck. I just can't seem to work around the fact that as soon as it gets to that rewrite code in apache then all post variables are lost. Some people say there's no way around it, but others say there is... I just can't find one :(. Plenty of sites use search engine friendly URLs tho so there has to be something :(